# JS anon functions in PHP (without anon function support)

Tags: php, anonymous-function

Let's say I have this JS code:

```
var events = ['start', 'stop', 'tick']
,   obj = ... // object with events
,   receiver = function(event_name, event_args){ // function to receive all events
        console.log(event_name, event_args);
    }
;

for(var i=0; i<events.length; i++){
    obj.on(events[i], (function(event){
        return function(){
            return receiver(event, arguments);
        };
    })(events[i]));
}
```

What I'm doing here is to route all events to function "receiver".

I'm trying to replicate this behavior in PHP, since I already have `obj.on` (`$obj->on`) functionality.

I would like to support (slightly) old PHP versions (5.1+), so I can't make use of anonymous functions (as well as passing variables to said functions).

Here's a tentative (and incomplete) version of the above code:

```
$events = array('start', 'stop', 'tick');
$obj = new ... ; // object with events
function receiver($event_name, $event_args){ // function to receive all events
    echo $event_name.' | '.print_r($event_args, true);
}

foreach($events as $event){
    $obj->on($event, ...); // ???
    // ???
        return receiver($event, func_get_arguments());
    // ???
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible approaches I can see is making use of `__invoke`:

```
$events = array('start', 'stop', 'tick');
$obj = new ... ; // object with events
function receiver($event_name, $event_args){ // function to receive all events
    echo $event_name.' | '.print_r($event_args, true);
}

class EventRedirector {
    public $event_name = '';
    public $redirector = '';
    public function __invoke(){
        $redirector = $this->redirector;
        return $redirector($this->event_name, func_get_args());
    }
    public function __construct($event_name, $redirector){
        $this->event_name = $event_name;
        $this->redirector = $redirector;
    }
}

foreach($events as $event){
    $obj->on($event, new EventRedirector($event, 'receiver'));
}
```